# How to parse xml without freezing GUI in iphone SDK?

Tags: iphone

How to parse xml without freezing GUI in iphone SDK ?

during parsing user can interact with gui components. But as i have seen most of the times GUI become freeze when xml parsing performed.

Answer (score 3):

Move parsing to the background thread, the easiest way will be to call:

```
[someObject performSelectorInBackground:@selector(parse) withObject:nil];
```

Remember that each thread requires separate NSAutoreleasePool for proper memory management so you will need to create it in the beginning of the parse method and drain in the end:

```
- (void) parse{
   NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
   ...
   [pool drain];
}
```

Comment: But i have a bit of complicated situation like:

Comment: [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(CustomMethod:) withObject:nil];
-(void)CustomMethod:(id)sender{
 NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];

 ObjXMLWebService = [[XMLWebService alloc]initWithSoapElements:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"value",@"Key",nil] 

BodyTitle:@"TitleOfXMLWebService" BodyAction:URLValue xsi:URLValue xsd:URLValue soap:URLValue Version:VersionNumber Encoding:EncodingUsed];

ObjXMLWebService.theRequest = [ObjXMLWebService ConfigureRequestWithContentType:ContentTypeValue SOAPAction:SoapActionValue To:URLValue];

Comment: [ObjXMLWebService ConnectWithRequest:ObjXMLWebService.theRequest]; 
 [pool drain];
}
-(void)ConnectWithRequest:(NSMutableURLRequest*)req{
......
......
Connection=[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:XMLConnection];
XMLConnection defines connection delegate methods, which also calls/sets another class for parsing delegate methods.

Answer (score 0):

Just as Vladimir mentioned, the background thread is the way to go. Check out the Apple sample code called SeismicXML as it does full asynch XML parsing with the NSXMLParser.